# how to get timescaledb version of the database

Tags: timescaledb

According to the [docs](https://docs.timescale.com/clustering/using-timescaledb/update-db):

> TimescaleDB supports having different extension versions on different databases within the same PostgreSQL instance.

I can get the installed version of the instance with this SQL command:

```sql
SELECT extversion
FROM pg_extension
where extname = 'timescaledb';
```

But how can I get the version of a specific database?

Notes:

- I prefer to get the version via sql (not psql)
- the reason for this is that we'd like to know if we must update the datebase (i.e. execute `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;`) or not

Comment: `SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension` gives you the installed extensions for the current connected database. Try this. 1. Connect to db1; 2. Create extension `create extension postgres_fdw`; 3. execute your query, you'll see postgres_fdw with it's version; 4. create new db2; 5. connect to db2 and execute the query, you will not see postgres_fdw in the list of extensions

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Turns out, that my assumption was wrong:

```sql
SELECT extversion
FROM pg_extension
where extname = 'timescaledb';
```

returns the version of the currently connected database.

Here is how we can find out the versions:

```sql
SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions
where name = 'timescaledb';
```

- `default_version`: is the version installed in the PostgreSQL server instance
- `installed_version`: is the version that the current database is using

**Example**:

When the extension used by the database is not up-to-date, the versions do not match:

```sql
SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions
where name = 'timescaledb';

 default_version | installed_version 
-----------------+-------------------
 1.4.1           | 1.4.0
```

now update the extension

- connect via `psql -X -U USER -W -D DBNAME`
- execute `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;`
- now the versions are the same

Comment: This is exactly what I would have suggested! Always nice when you answer your own questions :)

Comment: yes, sometimes it only takes a comment (thanks @Blagoj Atanasovski) and things become clearer :)

Comment: Running `\dx` in psql is always an easy way to get what versions of extensions are installed in postgres

Comment: What if after ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE; installed version don't change?

Comment: @MrJedi you should ask a new question - and include the info what the default/installed version are before you try to update.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `\dx`, as it shows the actually loaded extension version, check the "main" database `postgres` first:

```
$ psql
\dx timescaledb
\c some_database
\dx timescaledb
```

the output looks like this:

```
                                    List of installed extensions
    Name     | Version | Schema |                            Description                            
-------------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 timescaledb | 2.9.3   | public | Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data
```

or

```
psql -d database_name -c "\dx timescaledb"
```

`pg_available_extensions` will show available extension, however some database could be been created with much older extension version.

```
psql -c "SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions where name = 'timescaledb';"
 default_version | installed_version 
-----------------+-------------------
 2.13.0          | 2.10.1
```

Before extension upgrade you should check the supported paths and [release notes](https://docs.timescale.com/about/latest/release-notes/), for your version, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension_update_paths('timescaledb') WHERE source='2.9.3';
```

this corresponds to `sql` scripts on disk, where you can find all upgrade steps:

```
l /usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/timescaledb--2.9*
```

Extension upgrade can be done automatically (to the latest version):

```
psql  -X -c "ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;"
```

or to a specific version, assuming the upgrade path exists:

```
psql -X -c "ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE TO '2.13.0';"
```